# Facebook button signs in but doesn't do the functions he should do after signing in

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I am using Firebase in my android app. I use Facebook button to sign in in the app. when I press the sign in button it writes on the button logout which means that the button has signed in successfully but no thing happens from the things I wrote them in `onSuccess` method. I put toasts in all methods of the Facebook login but none of them appears at all.

This is my `handleFacebookLogin` method :

```
private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                    Toast.makeText(GeneralSignActivity.this, "نجح تسجيل الدخول", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    //updateUI(user);
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", 

                    task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(GeneralSignActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //updateUI(null);
                }
                    // ...
            }
        });
}
```

And this is the code of the button:

```
mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
LoginButton loginButton = findViewById(R.id.facebookBtn);
loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
        Toast.makeText(GeneralSignActivity.this, "onSuccess" + loginResult, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
        Toast.makeText(GeneralSignActivity.this, "onCancel" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
        Toast.makeText(GeneralSignActivity.this, "onError : " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // ...
    }
});
```